# I keep receiving an error message when I try and execute/ inspect something in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I am new to Java and the Eclipse platform. whenever I try and do anything I get the error message:

"Error occurred during initialization of boot layer java.lang.module.FindException: Module totalbeginer not found"

I'm not sure why this is happening and my instructors are not helpful at all, any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what is your jdk version?

Comment: What are you trying to do ? It is complaining about totalbeginer  module which probably you have created

Comment: What exactly you are trying to do, when this error is occurring? From your question I'm guessing if you are using java9 with module-info, then specify correct class name with full package to run the code.

Comment: I’m just trying to run a simple program like 2+2 as a test. It says “unable to connect to VM” and “socket closed”.